# Is it convention to return packets twice on streams? Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, sequelize.js

I'm attempting to get the headers of a particular table using Sequelize. In doing so, I found that the RawDataPackets returned are returned twice. Is this a convention for streams to send packets twice or more times? As shown below, I'm given the headers twice. If so, how do I handle this? I was thinking about using `_.chain.head.flatten.map.value` but if it is convention, I suppose there exists a better way.

```
/* Returns an array of headers
 * @param {string} tableName
 * @param {function} next
 * @returns {Array} 
 */
let getHeaders = function getHeaders(tableName, next) {
  let query = `SHOW COLUMNS FROM ${tableName}`;
  //TODO: change to spread
  db.sequelize.query(query)
    .then((results, metadata) => {
      console.log("flatten,",_.flatten(results));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err); 
  });
};

[ RowDataPacket {
  Field: 'id',
  Type: 'int(11) unsigned',
  Null: 'NO',
  Key: 'PRI',
  Default: null,
  Extra: 'auto_increment' },
RowDataPacket {
  Field: 'user_id',
  Type: 'int(11)',
  Null: 'YES',
  Key: '',
  Default: null,
  Extra: '' },
RowDataPacket {
  Field: 'question1',
  Type: 'varchar(11)',
  Null: 'YES',
  Key: '',
  Default: null,
  Extra: '' },
RowDataPacket {
  Field: 'question2',
  Type: 'varchar(11)',
  Null: 'YES',
  Key: '',
  Default: null,
  Extra: '' },
DUPLICATE STARTS HERE:
RowDataPacket {
  Field: 'id',
  Type: 'int(11) unsigned',
  Null: 'NO',
  Key: 'PRI',
  Default: null,
  Extra: 'auto_increment' },
RowDataPacket {
  Field: 'user_id',
  Type: 'int(11)',
  Null: 'YES',
  Key: '',
  Default: null,
  Extra: '' },
RowDataPacket {
  Field: 'question1',
  Type: 'varchar(11)',
  Null: 'YES',
  Key: '',
  Default: null,
  Extra: '' },
RowDataPacket {
  Field: 'question2',
  Type: 'varchar(11)',
  Null: 'YES',
  Key: '',
  Default: null,
  Extra: '' } ]
```